# deno_runtime running multiple invokes on single worker concurrently

Tags: rust

I'm trying to run multiple invocation of the same script on a single deno `MainWorker` concurrently, and waiting for their
results (since the scripts can be async). **Conceptually**, I want something like the loop in `run_worker` below.

```rust
type Tx = Sender<(String, Sender<String>)>;
type Rx = Receiver<(String, Sender<String>)>;

struct Runner {
    worker: MainWorker,
    futures: FuturesUnordered<Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output=(String, Result<Global<Value>, Error>)>>>>,
    response_futures: FuturesUnordered<Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output=(String, Result<(), SendError<String>>)>>>>,
    result_senders: HashMap<String, Sender<String>>,
}

impl Runner {

    fn new() ...
    
    async fn run_worker(&mut self, rx: &mut Rx, main_module: ModuleSpecifier, user_module: ModuleSpecifier) {
        self.worker.execute_main_module(&main_module).await.unwrap();
        self.worker.preload_side_module(&user_module).await.unwrap();

        loop {
            tokio::select! {
                msg = rx.recv() => {
                    if let Some((id, sender)) = msg {
                        let global = self.worker.js_runtime.execute_script("test", "mod.entry()").unwrap();
                        self.result_senders.insert(id, sender);
                        self.futures.push(Box::pin(async {
                            let resolved = self.worker.js_runtime.resolve_value(global).await;
                            return (id, resolved);
                        }));
                    }
                },
                script_result = self.futures.next() => {
                    if let Some((id, out)) = script_result {
                        self.response_futures.push(Box::pin(async {
                            let value = deserialize_value(out.unwrap(), &mut self.worker);
                            let res = self.result_senders.remove(&id).unwrap().send(value).await;
                            return (id.clone(), res);
                        }));
                    }
                },
                // also handle response_futures here
                else => break,
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The worker can't be borrowed as mutable multiple times, so this won't work. So the worker has to be a `RefCell`, and
I've created a `BorrowingFuture`:

```rust
struct BorrowingFuture {
    worker: RefCell<MainWorker>,
    global: Global<Value>,
    id: String
}
```

And its `poll` implementation:

```rust
fn poll(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
    match Pin::new(&mut Box::pin(self.worker.borrow_mut().js_runtime.resolve_value(self.global.clone()))).poll(cx) {
        Poll::Ready(result) => Poll::Ready((self.id.clone(), result)),
        Poll::Pending => {
            cx.waker().clone().wake_by_ref();
            Poll::Pending
        }
    }
}
```

So the above

```rust
self.futures.push(Box::pin(async {
    let resolved = self.worker.js_runtime.resolve_value(global).await;
    return (id, resolved);
}));
```

would become

```rust
self.futures.push(Box::pin(BorrowingFuture{worker: self.worker, global: global.clone(), id: id.clone()}));
```

and this would have to be done for the `response_futures` above as well.

**But I see a few issues with this.**

1. Creating a new future on every `poll` and then polling *that* seems wrong, but it does work.
   It probably has a performance impact because new objects are created constantly.
2. The same issue would happen for the response futures, which would call `send` on each `poll`, which seems **completely** wrong.
3. The `waker.wake_by_ref` is called on every poll, because there is no way to know when a script result
   will resolve. This results in the future being polled thousands (and more) times per second (always creating a new object),
   which could be the same as checking it in a loop, I guess.

**Note** My current setup doesn't use `select!`, but an `enum` as `Output` from multiple `Future` implementations, pushed into
a single `FuturesUnordered`, and then matched to handle the correct type (script, send, receive). I used `select` here because
it's far less verbose, and gets the point across.

Is there a way to do this better/more efficiently? Or is it just not the way `MainWorker` was meant to be used?

`main` for completeness:

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {

    let main_module = deno_runtime::deno_core::resolve_url(MAIN_MODULE_SPECIFIER).unwrap();
    let user_module = deno_runtime::deno_core::resolve_url(USER_MODULE_SPECIFIER).unwrap();

    let (tx, mut rx) = channel(1);
    let (result_tx, mut result_rx) = channel(1);

    let handle = thread::spawn(move || {

        let runtime = tokio::runtime::Builder::new_multi_thread().enable_all().build().unwrap();

        let mut runner = Runner::new();
        runtime.block_on(runner.run_worker(&mut rx, main_module, user_module));
    });

    tx.send(("test input".to_string(), result_tx)).await.unwrap();
    let result = result_rx.recv().await.unwrap();
    println!("result from worker {}", result);

    handle.join().unwrap();
}
```

Comment: Nitpick: `select!` accepts a pattern, so you can use `Some((id, sender)) = rx.recv() => ...` and `Some((id, out)) = self.futures.next() => ...` directly. This will stop the loop when the sender is closed or no more futures are there, thought, so you may want it only with `rx.recv()`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Yeah, I know, this was just cobbled together to illustrate the point. But in any case you would still need to handle any other pending futures until they were all completed, even if the channel had been closed before that.